# Kindly help me choosing right silicone from my mentioned list

Tags: aquarium

I am facing some challenges and need your help and advise. In my country, unfortunately, I don't find Aquarium safe sealant except 2 types. Only what I have seen in local stores are DAP and Loctite Aquarium safe small silicone tubes BUT they have clearly written that I can use for maximum for 30 Gallon and aquarium maximum height should be 45cm.

Kindly advise me shall I still go for DAP or Loctite Aquarium safe small silicone tubes for my 95 Gallon (356 Liter) Fish Tank ultra clear crystal glass 12mm thickness which

I had purchased from a local glass factory and still have to build/assemble as new very first time.

Dimensions of my Aquarium will be:

L= 121 cm
H = 55 cm
W= 55 cm
Thickness= 12mm

If not then kindly advise me what shall I use. Other than small tubes, I have below options only for Caulk silicones in my local market and this is what I have seen our local

Pet shops also using below to make their Aquariums.

- Soudal "Fix All" Crystal
- Soudal "Silirub 2" Universal
- GE Silglaze N10
- Bison "Poly Max" high tack
- DAP "Kitchen, Bath & Plumbing" Clear
- DAP "Window, Door & Siding" Clear
- DAP "Kwik Seal Ultra" Clear

Comment: is it not possible for you to order it online,the silicone for aquariums gets a lot harder and is a lot stronger than the types made for windows or toilet/shower/bath rooms.i do only know a few of the types in your question.

Comment: some of the things you need to know is here https://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Aquarium the type of silicone needs to be free of anti fungal and antibacterial chemicals,the best type is one made for constructing aquariums.

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. :) I'm curious, were you able to find what you were looking for online?